# Visual Studio 2013 failing to build after uninstalling Visual Studio 2012 - targets file not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have been getting several versions of the following error in my newest Visual Studio 2013 projects:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The problem is not a lack of an Azure SDK installation, but rather the fact that during build, $(VisualStudioVersion) is being reported as 11.0. I know this because if I edit the csproj files, remove the version check condition and hardcode the version value to 12.0, the build then succeeds.

I have not seen this error except after uninstalling Visual Studio 2012 which I no longer use.

Where is the "11.0" version number coming from? How do I get it to use the correct version number "12.0" as I imagine it would if I were working with a clean system installation?

**EDIT**
I think this may be an issue with .Net Demon. I will update this answer when I have more information.

**EDIT 2**
This is definitely some kind of .Net Demon issue though I have no idea what it is. No compile issues when .Net Demon is disabled.

Comment: did you try installing azure for vs2013? [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/)

Comment: @jackjop - not sure if you read my question - quoted from above: "The problem is not a lack of an Azure SDK installation, but rather the fact that..." (short answer- yes, it is installed)

Comment: did you uninstall azure for 2012 then?

Comment: So did you uninstall VS2012 before or after you installed VS2013?  I can sorta guess at that answer.  You convinced the VS2013 installer that opening old projects would not be a problem and that they won't have to be converted.  And then you jerked the floor mat, using an uninstaller without a time machine.

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks for the response. I uninstalled VS2012 a very long time after VS2013 was installed (like months later). Even so, the solution here was created entirely in VS2013, hence my confusion and the reason why I haven't been looking at issues with project version upgrades. I'm starting to think the problem isn't this at all, as I use .Net Demon and have just disabled it to discover that my solution now builds properly. I will report back upon further investigation.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend completely uninstalling Visual Studio 2012. Detailed steps to do this are [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441/EN-US#Force), but essentially:

> You can also remove Visual Studio 2012 and its optional shared packages by using a new command line switch. If you have multiple Visual Studio 2012 products installed, any common packages will still remain until all VS2012 products are removed.
>
> Even if you have already uninstalled the main product, you can still download the setup application and use it to run the following command to remove the rest of the packages except for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 and Visual C++ Runtime.
>
> Warning: Running this command may remove some packages even if they are still in use like those listed in Optional shared packages.
>
> 1. Download the setup application you used to originally install Visual Studio 2012. 
>      If you installed from media, please insert that media.
> 2. Open a command prompt.
>
>    - Click Run on the Start menu (Start + R).
>    - Type cmd and press OK (Enter).
> 3. Type in the full path to the setup application and pass the following command line switches: **/uninstall /force**
>
>    Example: `D:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force`
> 4. Click the Uninstall button and follow the prompts.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the page and uninstalled a lingering VS2012 update, though to no avail.